# What is the preferred workaround when an .aspx file's code-behind file is missing?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms, code-behind

In the source code for a VB ASP.NET website that I'm trying to get compiling, I've got a couple of "*The file 'bla.aspx.vb' does not exist*" errors; there is a corresponding .aspx file, but it's missing its companion .aspx.vb code-behind file.

The error msg displays because of this in the .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Bla.aspx.vb" Inherits="cms_ShowEscalatorRule" %>
```

To just get the project compiling (this is just for running the project locally, the code I change won't affect the production code), would it be preferable to:

```
0) Comment out that section entirely
1) Remove the "CodeFile="Bla.aspx.vb" portion
2) Add a code-behind file
```

If the last option is best, what needs to be in it for a minimal amount of code - just enough to prevent the "missing file" error?

It's rather macabre to me that there is no contextual menu item for .aspx files that allows a minimal corresponding .aspx.vb to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may *have* to have a file because the .aspx may have references (and you will have to recreate those in the code-behind) to items from the code-behind file.

The minimum that's needed is a class inheriting from Page:

```
public class Bla : System.Web.UI.Page
{ 
}
```

This - of course - is not mandatory - you may as well use the alternative approach and inline the code-behind in a server-side script block in the .aspx file. Former approach however is much neater.

Answer (score 0):

G. Stoynev basically had what I needed, but since this is VB, I had to change it to:

```
Public Class Bla
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
End Class
```

I have never used VB before, so I used [this](http://converter.telerik.com/) to make the translation.

Comment: In this circumstance your class in your .vb file needs to match that "inherits" in your page declaration. In this example: cms_ShowEscalatorRule. So if your page declaration is as you listed, you need `Public Class cms_ShowEscalatorRule Inherits System.Web.UI.Page`

Comment: ShowEscalatorRule.aspx has its first line: CodeFile="ShowEscalatorRule.aspx.vb" Inherits="cms_ShowEscalatorRule"
I'll try your suggestion in changing the class name in ShowEscalatorRule.aspx.vb from "ShowEscalatorRule" to "cms_ShowEscalatorRule" - that is what you mean, right?

Comment: I wasn't sure, but after re-reading your comment yes. The Inherits="..." has to match the class name exactly as you have in your CodeFile. It can all get rather annoying when things go awry, which is why it is a common suggestion to literally re-create the page so Visual Studio will create the designer and code-file for you.

Comment: How does one "re-create the page"?